# Deleting specific line from file

Tags: c++

These are the contents of my example file:

`abcdefg hijk lmnopqrstAB CSTAKLJSKDJD KSA FIND ME akjsdkjhwjkjhasfkajbsdh ADHKJAHSKDJH`

I need to find and delete the 'FIND ME' inside of the file so the output would look like this:

`abcdefg hijk lmnopqrstAB CSTAKLJSKDJD KSA  akjsdkjhwjkjhasfkajbsdh ADHKJAHSKDJH`

I have tried the following method of doing getline and then writing all of the contents except the FIND ME into a temporary file and then rename the temporary file back.

```
string deleteline;
string line;

ifstream fin;
fin.open("example.txt");
ofstream temp;
temp.open("temp.txt");
cout << "Which line do you want to remove? ";
cin >> deleteline;



while (getline(fin,line))
{
    if (line != deleteline)
    {
    temp << line << endl;
    }
}

temp.close();
fin.close();
remove("example.txt");
rename("temp.txt","example.txt");
```

but it doesn't work.
Just as a side note: the file has NO newline/linefeeds. So the file contents are all written in 1 line.

EDIT:

FIXED CODE:

```
while (getline(fin,line))
{
    line.replace(line.find(deleteline),deleteline.length(),"");
    temp << line << endl;

}
```

This gets me the results I expected. Thank you everyone for helping!

Comment: Can you use `sed` instead of C++?  Or is this hw?

Comment: All the content in file is in a single line? How do you compare the complete sentence with part of sentence?

Comment: I would rather not use unix commands if possible. It is not homework. I am just trying to do things for my own education

Comment: @VinayKumar I actually tried doing it with every line separated by a line feed, for some reason it also didn't work. But yeah, I need to find a line in a file and delete it from there.

Comment: I don't have this function getline(fin, line) in visual studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
line.replace(line.find(deleteline),deleteline.length(),"");
```

Comment: @Venraey: Glad that it worked! Why don't you add a note and a fixed version of code in your question? ;)

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone would like it I have converted Venraey's useful code into a function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
    
void eraseFileLine(std::string path, std::string eraseLine) {
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream fin;
    
    fin.open(path);
    // contents of path must be copied to a temp file then
    // renamed back to the path file
    std::ofstream temp;
    temp.open("temp.txt");

    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        // write all lines to temp other than the line marked for erasing
        if (line != eraseLine)
            temp << line << std::endl;
    }

    temp.close();
    fin.close();

    // required conversion for remove and rename functions
    const char * p = path.c_str();
    remove(p);
    rename("temp.txt", p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to clarify something. Although the answer provided by gmas80 could work, for me, it didn't. I had to modify it somewhat, and here's what I ended up with:

```
position = line.find(deleteLine);

if (position != string::npos) {
    line.replace(line.find(deleteLine), deleteLine.length(), "");
}
```

Another thing that didn't satisfy me was that it left blank lines in the code. So I wrote another thing to delete the blank lines:

```
if (!line.empty()) {
    temp << line << endl;
}
```